# How to set Cordova plugin variables in a Capacitor app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic-vue, wonderpush

I am attempting to set up the Wonderpush integration for Ionic using the docs at https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/mobile-push-notifications-ionic

The instructions say to install the plugin with:

`ionic cordova plugin add wonderpush-cordova-sdk --variable CLIENT_ID=YOUR_CLIENT_ID --variable CLIENT_SECRET=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET --variable SENDER_ID=YOUR_SENDER`

...but since my app is a Capacitor app, I must install the plugin with:

`npm install wonderpush-cordova-sdk`

I can’t figure out how to set the CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, and SENDER_ID when installing the plugin this way (there is no “`--variable`” flag for this command), and I’m getting a runtime error when running the app on my device saying those variables are missing. Do you know how I can populate these values? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to find where to put these variables. In `capacitor.config.json`, I made the following changes to the `"cordova": {}` element.

```
"cordova": {
    "preferences": {
      "WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_ID": "<YOUR-CLIENT-ID>",
      "WONDERPUSH_CLIENT_SECRET": "<YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET>",
      "WONDERPUSH_LOGGING": true,
      "WONDERPUSH_AUTO_INIT": true,
      "WONDERPUSH_REQUIRES_USER_CONSENT": false
    }
  }
```

Then, I ran `ionic cap sync`, started the app from the IDE, and success!

Comment: Why does WONDERPUSH map to wonderpush-cordova-sdk？

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor apps do not support variables while installing a plugin. This is because Capacitor apps are more native oriented and do  not provide configuration hooks via command line like Cordova does.

**To add variable with a plugin, you need to manually update AndroidManifest.xml for Android and Info.plist for iOS**. You can get more details about it here https://www.joshmorony.com/using-cordova-plugins-that-require-install-variables-with-capacitor/

Example: `<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>`

Although these configuration settings are missing in the current documentation of Ionic plugins but for popular plugins, you can check their native versions documents and update the platform files accordingly.

**Wondershare Android Configuration:** Look for "Alternate ways of specifying configuration options", Section

https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/android-sdk#alternate-ways-of-specifying-configuration-options

Answer (score 0):

You can automatically update the AndroidManifest.xml for Android and Info.plist for iOS using [Ionic's Trapeze tool](https://trapeze.dev/).